# How prove or disprove this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}|\sin{(x+k)}|}{n}=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin{x}|dx$

Tags: integration

prove or disprove
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}|\sin{(x+k)}|}{n}=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin{x}|dx$$

if this is right,and How prove it? Thank you

My idea maybe this can use Uniform distribution? and I don't prove it.

Comment: I have tried,and I can't true this right,and this problem is find limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}|\sin{(x+k)}}{n}$!

Comment: I believe you need a factor of $ \frac{1}{\pi}$ on the RHS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Lemma 1.** Let $\theta$ be a real number which is not a rational multiple of $\pi$. For
>   $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, we define $$I_n(m)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ne^{ikm\theta}$$
>   Then, 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n(m)=\left\{\matrix{0&\hbox{if}&m\ne0\cr1&\hbox{if}&m=0}\right.
> $$

*Proof.* Indeed, for $m\ne0$ we have
$$\left\vert I_n(m)\right\vert=\frac{1}{n}\left\vert\frac{e^{im(n+1)\theta}-e^{im\theta}}{e^{im\theta}-1}\right\vert\leq\frac{1}{n\vert \sin(m\theta/2)\vert}
$$
and the conclusion follows since $\theta\notin\pi\mathbb{Q}$.$\qquad\square$

> **Lemma 2.** Let $\theta$ be a real number with $\theta\notin\pi\mathbb{Q}$. Let $P$ be a trigonometric polynomial, $P(t)=\sum_{m=-r}^r c_me^{imt}$, and
>    define $$J_n(P,t)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nP(t+k\theta)$$
>   Then, 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}J_n(P,t)=c_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}P(x)dx
> $$

*Proof.* In fact 
$$
J_n(P,t)=\sum_{m=-r}^{r}c_me^{imt}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ne^{imk\theta}\right)
=\sum_{m=-r}^{r}c_me^{imt}I_n(m)
$$
and the conclusion follows by letting $n$ tend to infinity. $\qquad\square$

> **Proposition 3.** Let $\theta$ be a real number with $\theta\notin\pi\mathbb{Q}$. Let $f$ be a continuous $2\pi$-periodic function, and
>    define $$J_n(f,t)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(t+k\theta)$$
>   Then, 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}J_n(f,t)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)dx
> $$

*Proof.* Indeed, for $\epsilon>0$ there is a trigonometric polynomial $P_\epsilon$ such that
$$
\Vert f-P_\epsilon\Vert_\infty=\sup_{\mathbb{R}}|f(t)-P_\epsilon(t)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}
$$
It follows that
$$
\vert J_n(f,t)-J_n(P_\epsilon,t)\vert\leq\Vert f-P_\epsilon\Vert_\infty<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\tag{1}
$$
and also
$$
\left\vert \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)dx-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}P_\epsilon(x)dx\right\vert\leq\Vert f-P_\epsilon\Vert_\infty<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\tag{2}
$$
Finally, using Lemma 2. there is $N_\epsilon$ such that for $n>N_\epsilon$ we have
$$
\left\vert J_n(P_\epsilon,t)-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}P_\epsilon(x)dx\right\vert<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\tag{3}
$$
Combining $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ we obtain
$$
\forall\,n>N_\epsilon,\quad\left\vert J_n(f_\epsilon,t)-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)dx\right\vert<\epsilon.
$$
and the Proposition follows.$\qquad\square$

> **Application.** Taking $f(x)=|\sin(x)|$, and $\theta=1$ we see that
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|\sin(t+k)|= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|\sin(x)|dx.$$

Comment: It's Nice! Thank you very much!+1

Comment: Now this is an answer. =) +1

Comment: It's curious the result is $x$-independent. Is that a kind of Ergodic Theorem ?.

Answer (score 9):

**Claim:** If the continuous function $f(x)$ is periodic with period $T$ which is irrational, then

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(t + k)}{n} = \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T f(x) \, dx$$

**Hint:** The RHS calculates the average value of $f(x)$ (over 1 period). Show that the LHS is equivalent to (approximating) the average value of $f(x)$.

**Hint:** This is an application of the pigeonhole argument which shows that for any $ \epsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $n T$ is within $ \epsilon$ of an integer.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Hello,I think you hint is not usefull? because I have think it this hint,and I can't prove it? can you post your full solution?

Comment: You'd have to prove the LHS is independent of the choice of $t$, I guess.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes, that is true, and that's why I intentionally chose the variable $t$ instead of $x$.

Comment: do you know why  you answer  is updown vote is not hight? I think you post your full solution,then you updown is more.because I think this claim is not easy to prove it.

Comment: @math110 I'm not hard up for up votes, nor points. Thank you very much.

Comment: I like this answer because it makes me think that I could almost prove it using the first hint. Meaning, for large enough n, since T is irrational, any partition of [0, 1] would get uniformly filled so the whole interval would get uniformly filled, and there you are!

Comment: You need a *lot* more than the second hint though... you need a relatively strong statement concerning how the integers from $1$ to $N$ mod $\pi$ become uniformly distributed in $[0,\pi]$ as $N$ goes to infinity.